# Determining a PID of a task

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I need to be able to run or not run a script based on whether or not another process is running. The process is third-party image processing software called DenseCap. Is there a way to `wait` on a task that you don't know the PID of, but just the name of? When I run `ps -ef`, this is the process:

```
usr        4638   4536 93 14:57 pts/8    00:00:05 /home/usr/torch/install/bin/lu
```

I need to NOT run a certain script when *that* is running, but that certain script *needs* to be running when DenseCap isn't. I don't know how to retrieve the PID for it. Basically, there is one script I have that runs DenseCap, and another script that I have that runs a certain process that really should not be running while DenseCap is running. There is one script that runs them both simultaneously. I'm lost as to what to do. If you need to see the code, I can post it.

Comment: `pgrep <name>` would be helpful...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well in all the `pgrep` command would be helpful since you know the name of the command in question.

```
pgrep -l <name_of_command>
```

would list both the name and the `PID` so you can use that in your script.

See: `man pgrep`

Answer (score 1):

Another one you could use is the following command using `ps` with the option of showing `pid` and `cmd`.  The `pid` in this order would be the first part of the line.

```
ps -eo pid,cmd | grep <name> | grep -v grep
```

The only reason I like to use this one is in case I need to find a command by the switch that the command is running like a tunnel that uses something like `CfND`, but I might have extra ssh sessions running.

*Example:*

```
terrance@terrance-ubuntu:~$ ps -eo pid,cmd | grep CfND | grep -v grep
14908 ssh -CfND 4242 terrance@myvpntunnel.com
```

Hope this helps!